# cookie not working in Internet explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, cookies

I am adding a value to cookie using

```
Cookie testcookie = new Cookie ("test",test);
testcookie .setMaxAge(5*60);
response.addCookie(testcookie) ;
```

But I am not getting the cookie value in Internet explorer.
code of getting cookie value

```
Cookie cookies [] = getRequest().getCookies ();
    Cookie myCookie = null;
    if (cookies != null)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) 
        {
            if (cookies [i].getName().equals ("test"))
            {
                myCookie = cookies[i];
                String testval=myCookie.getValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

But the same works in firefox,cooies are enabled in IE.How to resolve this ?

Comment: are you sure you are accessing the same domains. i.e. http://site.com, and not http://www.site.com

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361231/persistent-cookies-from-a-servlet-in-ie and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716555/setting-persistent-cookie-from-java-doesnt-work-in-ie

Comment: Ya its repeated question but i am not getting the solution there

Comment: Have you checked your IE security zone allows persistent cookies from this site?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem these days, and I just found a solution. Try setting the cookie manually, as `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` does not allow you to set `Expires` attribute:

```
StringBuilder cookie = new StringBuilder("test=" + test + "; ");

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", Locale.US);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5*60);
cookie.append("Expires=" + df.format(cal.getTime()) + "; ");
cookie.append("Max-Age=" + (5*60));
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie.toString());
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleDateFormat solution works, although I noticed that the cookies weren't deleted at the time I expected. Seems that it printed the time in my local time, while the formatter presents it as GMT. If you set the calendar object to timezone GMT and use String.format, it will be formatted in the right timezone.

```
// Your values here
String name = "test";
String value = "test";
String path = "/";
int maxAge = 60;


StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(name);
sb.append("=");
sb.append(value);

sb.append("; path=");
sb.append(path);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, maxAge);
sb.append("; Expires=");
sb.append(String.format(Locale.US, "%1$ta, %1$td-%1$tb-%1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS GMT", cal));
sb.append("; Max-Age=");
sb.append(maxAge);

response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", sb.toString());
```