# fetch value from cookie giving issue

Tags: java, cookies, guice, inject

When user login first time I set the user value in cookie and then set cookie in the response.

This is my code snippet:

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userId","1");
cookie.setMaxAge((7*24) * 60 * 60);
response.addCookie(cookie);

But this is done in .java class. because I got HttpServletResponse object using guice injector:

```
HttpServletResponse response = injector.getInstance(HttpServletResponse.class);
```

Then I closes my application and again open then I read the value set in the cookie with cookie name. but I don't see the cookie with name userId set previously .I can see only JSESSIONID in coockie set.

So how can I get the usedId value from cookie. ?

Comment: was the setMaxAge() invoked with correct values ?

Comment: issue was because of the path that is set to cookie. Now its solved

Comment: Okies,,, then i hope you may close this question here ..

Comment: Is the problem in IE?  It could be a missing "Expires" header, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361231/persistent-cookies-from-a-servlet-in-ie

Comment: Issue is solved now :)