# CQ5 custom tag sets cookie in response, but is is not in response headers when using IE10

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-10, setcookie, aem

I have some custom code (in a tag) that will create a cookie and send it to the browser. This code works for Chrome, Firefox and IE9, but for some reason in IE10 the cookie will not even get sent in the response headers!

The code that creates the cookie is just Java standard:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("recently-viewed-producs-cookie", encryptedCookie);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setDomain(getSlingRequest().getServerName());
cookie.setMaxAge(COOKIE_AGE_IN_SECONDS);
getSlingResponse().addCookie(cookie);
```

Does anybody have an idea why this could happen? I encrypt the contens of my cookie, so there are no invalid characters (I believe).

Other cookies created by CQ5 are sent and the browser saves them. I checked the cookie settings for the browser and it is set to accept everything, including session cookies.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I did a little research and found that IE only accepts cookies if they have an expire date.  See here: [Persistent cookies from a servlet in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361231/persistent-cookies-from-a-servlet-in-ie).

I would try using the apache commons cookie class: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/Cookie.html.  This allows you to set the expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this
    response.addHeader(
    Set-Cookie: =[; =]...
    [; expires=][; domain=]
    [; path=][; secure][; httponly]),
remember to have space after every every semicolon

I got that from here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384321(v=vs.85).aspx